# Firebase Analytics. Custom item-scoped parameters are not shown in Debug View

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

We use @react-native-firebase/analytics version **14.2.1** in our React Native App

Everything works well, except one thing.
We track e-commerce events, such as `add_to_cart`, `begin_checkout`, `purchase`, etc. We pass the "items" array parameter to them, which contains the predefined GA4 parameters, that are described here - https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics/item

We decided to also pass our new custom parameter into the "items" array, that sounds like "item_condition". The problem is that we don't see this new custom parameter in the Debug View "Items" tab. It only appears in the "Parameters" tab on the Event scope level

[image: Debug View screenshot]

This is the code that serializes each item of "items":

[image]

However, as Google Analytics 4 says, it's actually possible to pass custom Item-scoped parameters - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/item-scoped-ecommerce

Also, we have created an appropriate custom dimension with the "Item" scope for this parameter in Firebase Console and Google Analytics 4 property.

NOTE: other custom parameters, that we pass as event-scoped parameters are tracked fine

Perhaps someone has encountered such an issue?

I've found a similar issue but on the native iOS App - [How to verify Firebase Item-scoped custom parameter are correctly sent on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034446/how-to-verify-firebase-item-scoped-custom-parameter-are-correctly-sent-on-the-co)